# Dimming option menu/android

Tags: android

Okay, so I have an option menu for my current app and it is the same with every class. okay, so I would like to know how to dim the options that are included in the menu when the selected class is already selected. For example, I have the Main Home on my option menu. When I am at the Main Home screen...it does appear on the option menu to click. How in the heck do you dim this? I tried looking on the android development page..but had no luck.. yet, I see it on other apps and it is driving me crazy! Surely, I am sure it is easy to mark the code out..but how can you do it! it is driving be bananas!

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/menu_design.html#dim_hide_menu_items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override [`onPrepareOptionsMenu`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) and disable the relevant menu item(s).

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    boolean ok = super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    if (ok) {
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(id_for_this_screen);
        if (item != null) {
            item.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    return ok;
}
```